# Android.mk conditions

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android-make

Is there any way to use conditional expressions in Android.mk? I need it to do smth like this:

```
IF arch = AREABI_V7
   *use path for my arm_v7 static libs*
ELSE
   *use path for arm static libs*
```

Answer (score 12):

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    ...
else
    ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
        ...
    endif
endif
```

Comment: You have missing space after second `ifeq` before the `(`. The build system errors on that.

Comment: "The NDK docs state that Android.mk "is really a tiny GNU Makefile fragment...".
Here are the docs about make conditionals:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html " //Taken from here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/UCqQ1L2kisE